# Why jQuery :first selector is not working here?

Tags: jquery

Why the below code of selecting first element in a group is not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("ul li:first").css("border", "1px solid red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" />
```

But if we try to select last element in a group then below code is working:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("ul li:last").css("border", "1px solid red");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" />
```

Any idea why :first is not working while :last is working?

**EDIT**

Sorry, no one could reply accurately to the real problem I have been facing. I just noticed through firebug that there is some extra weird HTML in my source code that I never wrote. This unnecessary code is causing issue in :first. Can anybody tell me how come it?

[image]

Comment: `:first` is working as expected, selecting the first `<li>` element. `:last` is also working as expected, selecting the last `<li>` element. What part of your code is not functioning the way you expect? Are you trying to select the **third** `<li>` element (the last element in the first `<ul>`)?

Comment: No, please check new updates in my question now.

Comment: please click the button on both snippet  "Run code snippet"

Comment: I already tried that one and I am not surprised to see them working because they are expected to do so. Please see the updates EDIT.

Comment: @user5307298 editted my answer, I already said you should define a class for the ul groups.

Comment: Ok that's alright but how did this weird code come? Which add-on or extension?

Comment: *no one could reply accurately to the real problem I have been facing* . how do we know your real code . ? unless you show to us .

Comment: @user5307298 How should we know which of your extensions, software, browser, framework or something else causes this. Anyway you will facing such problems often if you dont clearly define classes and id´s. Just imagine you have a huge project, in some weeks you add a footer with links. In an ul block, this would mean your button wouldnt work anymore it would select the last link in your footer.

Comment: @JYoThI I had already pasted my code and shown it to everyone. Someone should have thought of this that the code is written correctly then why it is not working as expected? There could be some another weird unexpected reason too for such problem.

Comment: @Doomenik Don't worry - it is just a test file not a project file. In projects, I always use class and id.

Comment: @user5307298 Is your question now answered ?

Comment: Yes @Doomenik. I accepted your answer and vote it up :)

Comment: Thank you, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Like I said you should define a class for your ul elements, I´m sure some framework or also any browser addon cann add unecessary elements. I nyour situation something created before an ul element. Simply give your ul elements a class like I edited.

*I probably think you want to choose the last element out of the first ul cause otherwise it would work. By adding ul:first it will select the first ul group. If you want to specify which group you want to work with, grant the ul element a class and write the selector like:
classXYZ li:last*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $(".ulgroup li:first").css("border", "1px solid red");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $(".ulgroup li:last").css("border", "1px solid red");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> 
    <li> unecessary Element from somewhere </li>
</ul>
<ul class="ulgroup">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ulgroup">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
<ul> 
    <li> unecessary Element from somewhere </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="First" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Last" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to select the last element in the first `<ul>` (the third `<li>` element overall), you can chain the two pseudo-selectors as `$("ul:first li:last")`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("ul:first li:last").css("border", "1px solid red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" />
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try first-child to select first element of group.

$("ul li:first-child").css("border", "1px solid red");